# Global dialog - how to?

Tags: android, dialog, global

Hello guys I created push notification using firebase and I want to set data to dialog that it should be global dialog. When notification comes app should show dialog it every activity. Please help me to create global dialog.Thank you in advance!

Comment: please when I do mistake tell me it

Comment: Make abstract dialog activity with dialog theme.

Comment: Will that dialog open when app is not running?

Comment: no it shouldn't work when app run Khemraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a **BaseActivity** which is need to be extended by all **Activity** ,
write a **LocalBroadcast** listener inside your BaseActivity class which **listen** Broadcasts from FireBaseMessaging service later make a dialog to show the message in your BaseActivity class with this you can able to show dialog on all activity (which extends base activity)

Answer (score 0):

Make a static function inside global class so that can be access from any other activity. Might the following code can help you.

```
    public class AppDialog {
       public static void showAppSettingDialog(Context context, String title, String msg,
                                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveClick,
                                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener negativeClick) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(context.getText(R.string.txt_countinue), positiveClick)
                .setNegativeButton(context.getText(R.string.txt_not_now), negativeClick);

        // create alert dialog
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Call the function as below:

```
 AppDialog.showAppSettingDialog(HomeActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.txt_read_permission_title), getString(R.string.txt_read_permission),
                    positiveClick, negativeClick);
```

You can either get you click in individual screen/activity by passing click in button click and fetch it as below :

```
    positiveClick = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              // your positive click
            }
        };

        negativeClick = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // your negative click
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        };
```